# How can I add a character to a string based on another string in C#?

Tags: c#, string, for-loop, char

I need to create a function that receives two strings, representing the word to be completed and the reference word, as well as a character corresponding to the proposed letter, and returns a string corresponding to the word to be completed in which all occurrences of the proposed letter have been added, relative to the reference word.

Example: `CompleterMot (".. IM ..", "ANIMAL", 'A')` should return `"A.IMA."`.
I don't understand how I can add all occurrences of the letter in the word that will be completed.

```cs
static string CompleterMot(string motincomplet, string motoriginal, char lettrepropos)
{
    string output = " ";

    for (int i = 0; i < motoriginal.Length; i++)
    {
        if((motoriginal[i] == lettrepropos))
        {
            output = motincomplet;
            if(output[i] != lettrepropos)
                output += (char)(lettrepropos);
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

In final I had `..IM..A` and I don't know how to fix my code.

Comment: For non french speakers : `CompleterMot` is `CompletWord`, `motincomplet` is `IncompleteWord`, `motoriginal` is `OriginalWord` and `lettrepropos` is `SuggestedLetter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you are doing this : `output = motincomplet;` this override the previous result. Then you append the expected letter to the output that gives `"..IM.." + 'A'` as result.

You can use a [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8) for string manipulation, that's pretty nice and allow you to directly change a character at a given index :

```
static string CompleterMot(string motincomplet, string motoriginal, char lettrepropos)
{
    var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(motincomplet);

    for (int i = 0; i < motoriginal.Length; i++)
    {
        if (motoriginal[i] == lettrepropos)
        {
            sb[i] = lettrepropos;
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```